# std::stoi, std::setbase, and an std::out_of_range error

Tags: c++, c++11

Using std::setbase to format a number to pass the numeric minimum of int to std::stoi throws an std::out_of_range exception, but I do not understand why.  If anyone can help me to better understand the reasoning behind the exception, I would greatly appreciate it.

**Code Snippet:**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string toString(const T x, const int base)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setbase(base) << x;
    return ss.str();
}   

int main(void)
{
    const int x = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    std::size_t index = 0;
    const auto base = 16;
    const auto s = toString(x, base);
    std::cout << "base-10: " << x << std::endl
              << "base-" << base << ": " << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::stoi(s, &index, base) << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

**Output:**

```
base-10: -2147483648 
base-16: 80000000 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  stoi 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: @ildjarn -- post that as an answer, and I can upvote it for you :)

Comment: I can't find any references to whether using `ss << std::setbase(16) << x;` is a bad idea for negative `x`. I see problems using your code even for `x = -10;`. The string coming out `ss << std::setbase(base) << x;` is `fffffff6`, which is probably also too large for an int.

Comment: It's because of an inconsistency: `std::setbase(16)` or `std::hex` converts the number to unsigned first, while `std::stoi` works on signed numbers.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of `setbase` to this question. Isn't it a massive red herring to your _real_ question, which is why `std::stoi("80000000", &index, 16)` throws?

Comment: Though as a _separate_ question I'm kind of interested in why `std::setbase` results in a positive value here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : `[ostream.inserters.arithmetic]/1` says that the textual representation of `int x` will be that of `static_cast<long>(static_cast<unsigned>(x))`, so it seems to me that it should only be positive if `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)`. But, I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @ildjarn It's also that `std::hex` is specified to format numbers like stdio's `%x`/`%X`, and that works on unsigned numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::stoX` functions will not return a negative value for a string that is not prefixed with `-`. `0x80000000` is 2<sup>31</sup>, which is not representable by a signed 32-bit integer, so there is overflow and consequently an exception is raised.